# trying to return two values form a method

Tags: java, javafx

I run a GUI to display each image from MySQL Database, it was working fine before i did not have any problems displaying the image when the next button was clicked,NOW i want to return not only the image but also the id from the same method which is why i changed from "Image" type to PAIR but i don't understand how to divide the two variables returned from that method:

Example of pair:

```
    public Pair<Integer,Image> image2()throws SQLException
        {
            int id;

            try {

                boolean anyResults = false;

                if (rs.next())
                {

                    anyResults = true;

                    Blob blob = rs.getBlob("image");

                    id = rs.getInt("id");


                    InputStream in = blob.getBinaryStream(1, blob.length());


                    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);


                    Image image1 = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(image,null);


                    return new Pair<>(id, image1);

                }
                else if (!anyResults)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not Found");
                }


            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

example of the next button clicked method:

```
public void NextButtomClicked() throws SQLException
    {
        //  this is what i used before =>   Image image1 = sql.image2();

        Pair<Integer, Image> image1 = sql.image2();

        this.imageView.setImage(image1);


    }
```

Comment: one is a key, the other the value. Maybe what you need is a composite object, instead of this. Either way, you are trying to put an image (nothing more) in a Pair<Integer, Image> type, that seems to be the problem.

Comment: What is the definition of your `Pair` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Pair<Integer, Image> pair = sql.image2();
Integer id = pair.getKey();
Image image = pair.getValue();
// now do what you want with id and image
```

You probably should also handle `null` case since your method can return it.

Answer (score 0):

Your are getting both values, there is nothing wrong with your Pair.

Afterwards though you set `imageView.image` to a `Pair<>` which does not work.

Your `image1` is no longer of type `Image` but of type `Pair`.

Your `NextButtomClicked()` should look something like this:

```
public void NextButtomClicked() throws SQLException {
    Pair<Integer, Image> pair = sql.image2();

    this.imageView.setImage(pair.getValue());
    this.imageView.setId(pair.getKey());
}
```

`pair.getValue()` returns the second parameter of your `Pair<>`. In your case the `Image`.

`pair.getKey()` returns the first parameter of your `Pair<>`. In your case the `Integer` (ID).